# getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated

Tags: java, android, file, android-sdcard

Suppose I have a Notepad-like app, where you can create and save text documents.

I want my users to be able to access those files (so that they can copy them to a computer, for example).

Before API 29, `getExternalStorageDirectory()` was a good choice - the directory was created **in the root of** `sdcard` and easily accessible. However, since API 29 it is deprecated. So now I have to use `getExternalFilesDir(null)` directory.

The problem is that that directory's path is something like `Android/data/your_package_name/files`, **which is very inconvenient** for the users. Many of them can't find it.
So, which method should I use?

Comment: Check the alternatives in the deprecated note here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116335/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-deprecated-in-api-level-29-java - these answers might be helpful.

Comment: You can use a classic file-picker module which you let start in the mentioned directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use getExternalFilesDir(), getExternalCacheDir(), or getExternalMediaDir() (methods on Context) instead of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().