# problem having accessing files in android 10 :- android studio

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, file-handling, android-security, android-10.0

Android 10 is not letting me access my files from external storage. In android 9 my app was working fine.I updated my phone from android 9 to android 10 and my app stopped responding.

**main_activity.java**

```
File directory;
    File path;
    File[] listfile;
    //File listFiles;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;

directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        path = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath()+ "/myfile/");

        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mycardview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(listimage.this, arrayList));

if (path.isDirectory()) {
            listfile =path.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < listfile.length; i++) {
                arrayList.add(listfile[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
            Collections.shuffle(arrayList);
```

**ERROR :**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.rajiv/com.example.rajiv.listimage}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3374)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3513)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2109)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>           at com.example.rajiv.listimage.onCreate(listimage.java:74)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7815)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7804)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1318)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)

I have checked on internet the problem is not in code 
google have applied a security patch in android 10 so the code isnt working i have also used permission on manifest as well as runtime permission ..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment check this link

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated android 10 `targetSdkVersion 29`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116335/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-deprecated-in-api-level-29-java

Comment: actually it works getExternalStorageDirectory(). thankyou for your answer I will not use this function from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another one caught out by Google changes.

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

You need to use MediaStore or Storage Access Framework (SAF), details https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared for files outside of your App's private directories.

Though as a quick fix is to temporarily opt out https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/compatibility but this will only work until Android 11