# how to make app's folder in API 29 or higher?

Tags: android, api, directory

I have an app which needs to create its own folder in memory
I use this code and it's working up to android 9 (API 28)
but when I installed it on android 10 (API 29) it doesn't make folder and app closes without reason.
Here is my code:

```
String V0;
File Train_Folder;
Train_Folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Navgan/" + V0 + "/");
```

this folder `Navgan` is unique for the app and no any other apps use this folder.
I tried some solutions suggested on SO but didn't work for me.

Thank you

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116335/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-deprecated-in-api-level-29-java

Comment: Thank you very much