# how to create a folder and file in internal storage using kotlin

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, nativescript

I'm trying to create a file and folder on my internal storage
in manifest i have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

these permissions.

```
fun test(view: View) {
        try {
            val myObj = File("filename.txt")
            if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
                println("File created: " + myObj.name)
            } else {
                println("File already exists.")
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            println("An error occurred.")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

i got this

```
An error occurred.
java.io.IOException: Read-only file system
```

i tried so many other thing from javatpoint to official java and kotlin tutorials.
but none worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok got it,not specifying proper path.

```
        val data: String = "om namah shivaya"
        val path = this.getExternalFilesDir(null)

        val folder = File(path, "avalakki")
        folder.mkdirs()

        println(folder.exists()) // u'll get true 

        val file = File(folder, "file_name.txt")
        file.appendText("$data")
```

then to check this, navigate to

Android -> data -> com.your.pkg_name -> files ->

There will see files got created.

***note:- we can use different paths***

`val path = this.externalCacheDir`
Android -> data -> com.your.pkg_name -> cache ->

`val path = this.externalMediaDirs.first()`
Android -> media

`val path = this.getExternalFilesDirs(null).first()`
`val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()`

print and check what the path is.

Comment: plz tell me is it possible to paste that file inside android/data/ instead of android/data/"com.your.pkg_name "

Answer (score 1):

**Actual in June 2023**

In order to write to Internal Storage from your activity, make use of this snippet:

```
    applicationContext.openFileOutput("filename.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
        it.write("your text".toByteArray())
    }
```

**Note!** Use `applicationContext` instead of `context`

However, **now it is stronly advised to use DataStore**: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create file in root directory which is not permitted. You can create files in the internal storage/SD card using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.  Use the below code:

```
val myObj = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"filename.txt")
```

Note:  **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated in API level 29 java**

Please refer [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() deprecated in API level 29 java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116335/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-deprecated-in-api-level-29-java) for more details.

Comment: sorry man, i won't use it even it worked. because it was deprecated

Comment: Did you ever fix this.