# How to fetch all images of a folder in android 10?

Tags: android, android-10.0

I am facing an issue to fetch all images of a folder in android 10, because `getExternalStorageDirectory()` and `getExternalPublicStorageDirectory()` has been deprecated in android 10, so how to load in android 10??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() deprecated in API level 29 java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116335/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-deprecated-in-api-level-29-java)

Comment: Actually getExternalFilesDir(), getExternalCacheDir() likes methods save the content in app specfic internal storage, but my content is saved outside the app specific internal storage, so how to fetch data from that location in android 10...