# Permission denied. Save File to SD Card on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sd-card, permission-denied, android-external-storage

I am trying to simply save a File to my Device. I added the Permission in the Manifest and the app does ask me for permission to access the storage but when I click "Save File" my "permission failed" Toast pops up. Maybe I don't ask for permission correctly. I tried it on my Samsung S10 and on the emulator and on both devices it does not work.
If I try to use it on my real device a second time, the app just crashes. However, that does not happen on the emulator
Hope someone can help me.
Thanks already.

////code

```
package com.example.writeexeternalstorage;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Permission;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText fileName;
    EditText text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private boolean isExternalStorageWriteable(){
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void writeFile(View v){
        if(isExternalStorageWriteable() && checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            File textFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName.toString());

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(textFile);
                fos.write(text.getText().toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "File saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else if(isExternalStorageWriteable() == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "External Storage is not writable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if(checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == false) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public boolean checkPermission(String permission){
        int check = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permission);
        return (check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell full path of the file you try to write to. And Android version of devices used.

Comment: Place also a Toast in that catch block.

Comment: i dont have any specific path to write to. this is simply to learn how the interaction with external storage works because i was not able to read anything from a file on my sdcard.
my phone has Android 10

Comment: Of course there is a specific path that you use. I sse it and i could tell you but would rather see you telling me. And... it has nothing to do with a removable micro sd card your path.

Comment: I honestly dont quite understand how "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" works but it since i didnt add any other directory or folder to put my file in it will just save the, for example .txt file onto the card (or the internal storage because the internal storage is declared as sdcard in android studio) but i was trying to figure out wich one.

Comment: Have a look at string `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` and you will see the path i asked you for.

Comment: Yeah I mean its going to be in root directory of my external storage

Comment: Hmmm... can be... But what i meant is that you would tell us the value of that path. Which full path is it? You still did not tell.

Comment: I have honestly no idea what are you talking about i am very sorry

Comment: `Toast.makeText(.... Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() ...).show();` Which value do you see?

Comment: "/storage/emulated/0" and now i am really confused becaus I have no idea what that is

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() on an API level greater than 29 then it would not work, because starting from API level 29 android made this function deprecated.
Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116335/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-deprecated-in-api-level-29-java) would answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the link i have read into it and will try it out later !

Comment: `on an API level greater than 29` You mean: `on an API level equal and greater than 29`

Comment: equal and greater than