# getExternalMediaDirs() is deprecated in Android

Tags: android, file-storage

I am using the following method which I borrowed from [this official camera github app](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/MainActivity.kt):

```
    /** Use external media if it is available, our app's file directory otherwise */
    fun getOutputDirectory(context: Context): File {
        val appContext = context.applicationContext
        val mediaDir = context.externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, appContext.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else appContext.filesDir
    }
```

But now Android Studio tells me that `externalsMediaDirs` is deprecated. How I change it so that it works?

Comment: You do not have to change anything as deprecated does not mean that it does not work. Did you try? Please tell which path(s) it gives.

Comment: Please see this answer it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/57116787/14884388

Answer (score 1):

Usually deprecation comes with a recommendation for a newer API and/or a reason why it is blocked.

This is the deprecation message from [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalMediaDirs()):

> These directories still exist and are scanned, but developers are encouraged to migrate to inserting content into a MediaStore collection directly, as any app can contribute new media to MediaStore with no permissions required, starting in Build.VERSION_CODES.Q.

According to the message it seems like those directories are safe to use (for now, at least).
However, newer API is available which does not require storage permission (That `MediaStore`).