# File path exist always return false Android Above Q

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, scoped-storage

**Some one solve my code**

```
private fun isFileExists(): Boolean {
    var checked = false
    try {
        val filePath= this.applicationInfo.dataDir + PATH_SUFFIX + FILE_NAME
        val file = File(filePath)
        if (file.exists()) {
            checked = true
        }
    } catch (ignored: Exception) {
    }
    return checked
}
```

**Bellow android Q Its return true if exists, but Above Q it return always false**

Comment: You do not have access to other apps' portions of external storage on Android 10 and higher.

Comment: Yes I know but , I want to find my own application this.applicationInfo.dataDir

Comment: Please tell full path. Tell value of fullPath. How should we know else?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below code.

```
<manifest ... >
<!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
     Android 10 or higher. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>


private fun isFileExists(): Boolean {
        var checked = false
        try {
            val privateTempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

            val filePath= privateTempDir.absolutePath + PATH_SUFFIX + FILE_NAME
            val file = File(filePath)
            if (file.exists()) {
                checked = true
            }
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
            ignored.printStackTrace()
        }
        return checked
    }
```

I hope it works for you!!

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() depreciated api 29 . The mentioned code working bellow 29 after update api above it returns false

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116335/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-deprecated-in-api-level-29-java