# Need help finding a file that my Android app created

Tags: android, missing-data

A few years ago, I wrote an Android app that reads my own expenses_db file and copies the rows to a .csv file. The .csv file is supposedly in an "expenses" subdirectory of a folder that I found using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
For a long while, I could use a file explorer to find my .csv file in that "expenses" directory. But recently, that "expenses" directory seems to be empty. The app is still writing to the expenses_db file. (I know this because I can view the database's contents from within my app).
I suspect that this change comes from some change in Android permissions, but I don't know what it is, or what's the simplest way to fix it.
Any help?

I used Root Explorer to search for files named "expenses". I also tried to find the "expenses" file using Servers Ultimate FTP. In neither case could I find the "expenses_db" database file either.

Comment: You need to provide more detail as to how you wrote the app (manifest / permissions / what is the targetSDK) and how you are running/testing now (device / OS version). See: [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() deprecated in API level 29 java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57116335/295004) for some details.